# AWS S3 Bucket image download in batch using PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS S3 bucket for file storage and i have more than 10k QR code, i want to download all in my admin panel but problem is that when i download all those images my AWS instance (micro) CPU use 99.76% and system indicate that you can not download number of files. any one have idea about how to download number of images from AWS and what could be possible solution.

Comment: create a zip before downloading... it will minimize the number of  requests but the storage will increase

Comment: And how to zip create using php, it will also take time to create zip for 10k images? what about timeout request and memory consumption.

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirements? Is your question how to use the AWS PHP SDK to download files from Amazon S3? What is the "admin panel" you mention — are you referring to the Amazon S3 management console? Is your desire to download all the files to an Amazon EC2 instance? Feel free to edit your question to clarify what you are wanting to achieve and what problems you are facing. If possible, please show your code and error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

Install it on your computer, then use a command to download the files:

- [`aws s3 cp --recursive`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)
- [`aws s3 sync`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

If you are running it on an Amazon EC2 instance, it will use credentials from the IAM Role that is assigned to the instance. If you are running the command on  your on computer, use `aws configure` to save the credentials.

Comment: [What Is the AWS SDK for PHP Version 3? - AWS SDK for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html)

Comment: Yes i am using latest AWS SDK version. Version 3 of AWS SDK for PHP